# ASP.NET Core 2 - How to remove scaffolded routes?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

ASP.NET Core 2.x includes some pre-made scaffolded routes, like the login page, settings, etc.  I am working on something that only has OAuth login buttons, and no settings.  This means that I don't want users to be able to register with an email, and I don't want any settings pages.

I can remove the link to things like the Settings page , however the routes still exist and can be accessed by typing them in.  How do I **disable** these routes so they are completely inaccessible?

Basically everything under the `/Identity/Account/*` route, except for the login page should not be available.

Comment: Take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53559810/how-to-remove-default-asp-net-core-identity-endpoints

Answer (score 2):

What you're referring to is the default Identity UI. It's included whenever you register Identity with `services.AddDefaultIdentity` or explicitly call `AddDefaultUI` when registering via the other `IServiceCollection` extensions (`AddIdentity`/`AddIdentityCore`). You cannot pick or choose what will or will not be included in the default UI, so if you don't want a part of it, then you cannot use it at all. Therefore, change the `services.AddDefaultIdentity` line to `services.AddIdentity` instead.

Once that's complete, you can use the Identity scaffold to include certain parts of the default UI in your application. Right click on your project and choose `Add` > `New Scaffolded Item...`. Then pick `Identity` on the left, and `OK` to use the only Identity scaffold available. On the resulting window, you can check the pages you want to include, and then click `OK` again.

Comment: So if I want to disallow registering with an email, the best thing to do would be to add the related scaffolded items and then make that page blank or redirect elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

For disabling the specific route for `Razor Page`, you could try `IAsyncPageFilter`.

```
public class DisableIdentityAsyncPageFilter : IAsyncPageFilter
{
    public DisableIdentityAsyncPageFilter()
    {
    }

    public async Task OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync(
                                        PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
    {

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(
                                        PageHandlerExecutingContext context,
                                        PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Identity") &&
            !context.HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Identity/Account/Login"))
        {
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(404);
        }
        else
        {
            await next.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

And then configure in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddMvc(options => {
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(DisableIdentityAsyncPageFilter));
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```